# Old push notification received when a new one is sent

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

this issue is happening using Apple Push Notification service.

In an instant messaging app, after a heavy(?) testing session (about 2000 PN sent from our server in 15 min), when a new PN is sent (3 hours after), the device gets one of the PN sent during the 15 min testing session.

The issue stops when the app is shut down and launched again, the "PN stack" seems to be cleared and when a new PN is sent it's received in the device.

This behavior was observed on iPhone 4 and 5 (no IOS 7) with a server running on IIS7 (MoonAPNS for PN), but it is not easy to reproduce.

A bit of research was done on our app and in some forums and nothing obvious appeared.

Is this a known issue and there is something that can be done to prevent it?

Comment: Are you using the development gateway or the productive one?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that's your situation, but maybe coalescing is your culprit. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23, under "Some Notifications Received, but Not All" explains this behaviour. Hammering the APNS with so many PNs might cause not only this though, if you do it too often Apple might ban your IP out of fear for DDOS :-P

Comment: Here's what I think: After the devices fails to do the round-trip in time after xx PNs, the server timeouts and caches the last PN. After you send your next PN, the server detects the cached PN and sends this one instead. Something like this?